# What are the various propulsion systems on the ISS?

Tags: iss, propulsion, space-station

I understand there is a propulsion system on each of Zvezda and Zarya (NTO-UDMH I assume, given their heritage, though set me straight if you know better). Do any of the other permanent ISS space station modules have a propulsion system and what type is it?

There's no need to count the past and present visiting vehicles: Shuttle, Soyuz,  ATV, HTV, Progress, Cygnus and Dragon.

That said, it would be interesting to know which permanent ISS propulsion systems can be resupplied by each visitor. Does the resupply vehicle only resupply the module to which it is attached or is there plumbing between permanent modules?

Comment: I can confirm Zvezda uses NTO-UDMH: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S5.80

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand there is a propulsion system on each of Zvezda and Zarya.

There was a propulsion system on Zarya. The attitude jets and main engines on that module have been permanently disabled. The propellant tanks are still used, but only to supply the jets and engines on Zvezda.

> Do any of the other permanent ISS space station modules have a propulsion system and what type is it?

There were plans for a ISS Propulsion Module on the US side of the Station, but that was cancelled long ago. It was never built. There is also the Interim Control Module, intended as a backup for Zvesda, and this was built. It currently is located in some warehouse in Washington, D.C.

Bottom line: No permanent ISS space station modules other than Zveda have a propulsion system. Zvesda and visiting vehicles are the only options.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been looking at wiki at the smaller modules attached to the Russian segment. It appears, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirs_%28ISS_module%29, that Pirs and Poisk have through plumbing so that propellant delivered by Progress can be transferred to Zvezda, and also to Zarya for storage.  I'm just wondering how flexible the system is, does any one know if the through-plumbling also exists on Rassvet, the module at the front of Zarya?

Comment: Where I'm heading with this, and it might become my next full question, is the implications for a propulsion system of having propellant transferred in and out. Is everything managed with the pressure head from an N2 / He tank or are electric pumps used? Is the tank filled from its outlet boss, i.e. with filling propellant and possibly gas bubbles passing "backwards" through any surface tension devices used to keep the outlet boss supplied with propellant?

Comment: @Puffin -- Those are separate questions. It's best not to ask new questions (or answer them) in comments at this site because comments can be and oftentimes are deleted. Instead, ask those questions as questions.